# Why does this cpp see a function when its corresponding header does not?

Tags: c++

This one is making me scratch my head too long.

I have the following in a header test.h:

```
inline void anything(){
std::cout<<" anything "<<ii;
}
```

Then I have a.h, which includes test.h:

```
class Fooness{
public: 
Fooness(){
    anything(); //compiler reports "use of undeclared identifier"
    };
};
```

HOWEVER, if I simply move the function definition to a.cpp:

```
Fooness::Fooness(){
anything();
}
```

It works. a.cpp includes test.h which includes a.h. Why is `anything()` only visible in a.cpp not a.h?

Comment: Is a.h included in test.h?

Comment: rescinding my comment, leemes is all over that. =P

Comment: Then thats the problem. a.h is looking for `anything()` before test.h defines it.

Comment: @leemes I wish I could bump that comment up more than once, btw. nice catch.

Comment: a.h includes test.h or test.h includes a.h. you seem to be mentioning both

Comment: @WhozCraig I ran into this situation far too often by myself... I *had* to see it ;)

Comment: @SebbyJohanns I added a longer explanation of the situation after you accepted my answer. I want to notify you so you can have a look now. :) See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out in the comments, you included `a.h` in `test.h` and *vice versa*. This introduces errors as functions and classes being "undefined" because of a *cyclic dependency*, also known as *cross-include*.

In your case, when a `.cpp` file includes `test.h`, it *first includes `a.h`* and **then** defines the function `anything();`, which is obviously not what you want, since when processing `a.h`, `anything()` is undefined.

Your code expands to something similar to this, when compiling a unit which includes `test.h` (before `a.h`), which by itself includes `a.h` before anything else:

```
/* INCLUDED FROM a.h */
class Fooness{
public: 
Fooness(){
    anything();
    };
};

inline void anything() {
    ....
}
```

As you see, there is no `anything()` defined when you use it. However, if a compilation unit includes `a.h` (before `test.h`), which itself includes `test.h`, it expands to something like this:

```
/* INCLUDED FROM test.h */
inline void anything() {
    ....
}

class Fooness{
public: 
Fooness(){
    anything();
    };
};
```

So the order is correct.

To make it work in both situations, you can **forward-declare** `anything()` in `test.h` before you include `a.h`:

**Corrected version of *test.h***:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

void anything(); // forward-declaration

#include "a.h"   // <-- this is important to be *below* the forward-declaration

inline void anything() {
    ....
}

// more stuff

#endif
```

Then, when including `test.h` (before `a.h`), it expands to the following:

```
void anything();

/* INCLUDED FROM a.h */
class Fooness{
public: 
Fooness(){
    anything();
    };
};

inline void anything() {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Well, it _is_ a problem _per se_ -- it's a cyclic dependency which may never be fully resolved.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I wanted to emphasize that you *can* cross-include it (it's not forbidden), but that the *real* problem is the *symbol dependency*, if we can call it like that.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that "undeclared identifier" is about `anything()` and not about `ii` which I see in `operator<<`...